# Netbeans - How to do setsize() of a frame?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, frame

I have made a GUI in Netbeans. Now I want that the frame size should remain constant, means the user cannot do maximize or restore the frame.

When I go the the frame properties dialog box, I didn't see any property that allow me to set the size of the frame.

I opened the frame properties dialog box by right clicking on the "FrameView" node in the "Inspector" window.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "`resizable`". That will prevent the user from changing the window size.

Next, set the `preferredSize` property (if you're using java.awt.Frame instead of JFrame set the `minimumSize` property instead).